# Map method on huge array doesn't work

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, dataset, key-value

I have a huge array containing 200.000 JSON objects. Those objects have certain key/values that I don't want because they just eat up performance. I want to clean up (remove certain key/value pairs) the array from those key/value pairs .

I tried:

```
var result = data.map(elem => {
  return {
  name: elem.name,
  city: elem.city,
  age: elem.age,
  latitude: elem.latitude,
  longitude: elem.longitude,
  };
});

console.log(result);
```

When I tried this method on a way smaller array with multiple JSON objects it worked but the problem is I need to clean up a way bigger array (file has +50mb). When I try to load the index.html of the array the browser doesn't load it. I guess the file I want to clean up is too big for this approach … what could I do? (The file is embedded correctly in my index.html)

Comment: [There's no such thing as a "JSON object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)

Comment: Maximum array size also matters.

Comment: What do you mean exactly when you say "The browser doesn't load it"? You might just have a problem with how you load the file

Comment: Also, how many objects are we talking about?

Comment: why not update the array *in situ*?

Comment: @atomrc We are talking about 200.000 objects

Comment: @NinaScholz what do you mean with _in situ_?

Comment: @UnknownUser, it means in place, in this case, you mutate the array, instead of creating a new one.